# Join two MySQL SELECT statements containing one WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

How can I join the two select statements below to work as one statement? I would like the result to appear in one table. Thanks for your help.

First statement -

```
SELECT Account_ID, SUM(Profit_Loss) AS Starting_Balance
FROM client_ledger_history
WHERE Summary = 'Cash In'
GROUP BY Account_ID WITH ROLLUP
```

Second statement -

```
SELECT
    client_ig_client_list.Account_ID,
    client_ig_client_list.`Name`,
    Share_Status,
    Forex_Status,
    Index_Status,
    Share_Weighting,
    Forex_Weighting,
    Index_Weighting,
    SUM(
        client_ledger_history.Profit_Loss
    ) AS Current_Balance
FROM
    client_ledger_history
LEFT JOIN client_ig_client_list ON client_ig_client_list.Account_ID = client_ledger_history.Account_ID
GROUP BY
    Account_ID WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you provided sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a join into a nested table

```
SELECT
client_ig_client_list.Account_ID,
Starting_Balance,
client_ig_client_list.`Name`,
Share_Status,
Forex_Status,
Index_Status,
Share_Weighting,
Forex_Weighting,
Index_Weighting,
SUM(client_ledger_history.Profit_Loss) AS Current_Balance 
FROM
    client_ledger_history LEFT JOIN client_ig_client_list ON client_ig_client_list.Account_ID = client_ledger_history.Account_ID 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT Account_ID, SUM(Profit_Loss) AS Starting_Balance 
FROM client_ledger_history WHERE Summary = 'Cash In' GROUP BY Account_ID WITH ROLLUP) as client_ledger_aggreagated_history 
ON client_ledger_aggreagated_history.Account_ID = client_ledger_history.Account_ID
    GROUP BY Account_ID WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Thanks @MrMush however I am getting the error below when I try your statement.

[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'client_ledger_aggreagated_history.Profit_Loss' in 'field list'

Comment: Oops, fixed it, please try again.